# Radial (star-like) distortion of a circle in Gimp

Tags: gimp, filter

I'm new to Graphic Design. I use Gimp and I'm trying to create a blurry flower-like or star-like shape, starting from the circle below. I have a hard time looking up how to do this, because I don't know what this effect is called and I can't find an example.

[image: fuzzycircle]

The following is the closest I can find to an example, but I personally want a more "pointy" look.

[image: flower]

I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: Better to use Inkscape for things like this. It's also free and Open Source like GIMP. It's much easier to make shapes like stars. [see example](https://imgur.com/YvXRMw7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pointy star with `Filters > Render > Gfig`. Two ways to round it:

1. Use the `Stroke` option of GFig. This strokes the outline with the current brush, so the roundness of the tip of the rays is defined by the size of the brush (as set in the Paintbrush options):

[image]

2. Use only the "Fill" option to get a pointy star. Render the star on a new transparent layer. Then

   - Layer > Transparency > Alpha to selection
   - Select > Feather (50px in the exemple below)
   - Select > Sharpen

[image]

Selection and inverted selection filled with a `Shaped (Spherical)` gradient on a new layer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the free selection tool (=lasso) and make a starlike selection:

[image]

Invert that selection (Select > Invert) and apply Color > Curves (or levels) to turn the outer part black:

[image]

You may apply Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur to get the original blurry look:

[image]

So, this is made by starting from your original image and it resembles a star. Done.

BTW. If you expected something else you should mention what you actually want.